# get model name in yii for jquery

Tags: yii

In my `CJuiAutoComplete`, I currently have the code below.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                'name'=>'ABCForm[postcode]',
                'id'=>'ABCForm_postcode',
                   ..........
             ));
```

Is there a way to get the model name so I don't have to hard code it in my jquery?

In case I change the name in the future, I don't have to go though all my JS code to change the `name` and `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use [`CHtml::activeId`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeId-detail) and [`CHtml::activeName`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeName-detail) as it fits Yii much better. So your code would look like:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', [
   'name'=>CHtml::activeName($model, 'postcode'),
   'id'=>CHtml::activeId($model, 'postcode'),
   //..........
]);
```

EDIT: I have never used `CJuiAutoComplete` before but wouldn't it make more sense to use its `model` and `attribute` widget parameters (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJuiInputWidget#model-detail):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', [
   'model'=>$model,
   'attribute'=>'postcode',
   //..........
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have passed a model using the variable `$model` to your view, you can try:

```
get_class($model)
```

Comment: `$this->model` would work if the model is sitting inside the controller, not passed to the view (Yii1 doesn't have a View object, only controller); so if you pass model to the view with name `model` something to the view it should just be `get_class($model)`